# Adding site to Google Webmaster using Google API

Tags: java, api, google-api, google-search-console

I'm trying to make my life easier by writing a small java program that will add sites to a webmaster account and verify them.

I'm using the sample code google have in their api documents:

```
public static SitesEntry insertSite(WebmasterToolsService myService, 
    String siteUrl) throws IOException, ServiceException {
  SitesEntry entry = new SitesEntry();
  OutOfLineContent content = new OutOfLineContent();
  content.setUri(siteUrl);
  entry.setContent(content);
  System.out.println("Site: " + siteUrl + " now being added.");
  return myService.insert(getSitesFeedUrl(), entry);
}
```

However, I keep getting :

```
Site: www.mydomain.com now being added.
com.google.gdata.util.InvalidEntryException: Bad Request
[Line 1, Column 406, element atom:content] No xml:base established--need an absolute URI.: www.mydomain.com
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:602)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:564)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:560)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.insert(Service.java:1409)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.insert(GoogleService.java:613)
    at sample.webmastertools.WebmasterToolsClient.insertSite(WebmasterToolsClient.java:183)
    at sample.webmastertools.WebmasterToolsClient.main(WebmasterToolsClient.java:449)
```

I know that the code communicates with my account since I ran also the `printUserSites()` function which prints all the websites under the webmaster account.

Can someone help me figure out what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

try with http://yoursite.com instead only yoursite.com